# recover the Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I have dual boot on my laptop, win 7 & ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My win 7 gets crashed So I reinstall it. But after the installation of win7 my ubuntu is unaccessible to me. The windows loader gets stared, intead of linux loader. So how I recoverd back my ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following..

- In windows Disk Management you can check if you haven't deleted any Ubuntu related partition
- Put the Ubuntu installation disk back and try the recovery mode